# How to read element from a vector pointer?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, c++03

I need to access a vector pointer elements, I have the following code for my animation structures (simplified here, unnecessary variables cut off):

```
struct framestruct {
    int w,h;
};
struct animstruct {
    vector<framestruct> *frames;
};

vector<framestruct> some_animation; // this will be initialized with some frames data elsewhere.

animstruct test; // in this struct we save the pointer to those frames.

void init_anim(){
    test.frames = (vector<framestruct> *)&some_animation; // take pointer.
}

void test_anim(){
    test.frames[0].w; // error C2039: 'w' : is not a member of 'std::vector<_Ty>'
}
```

The array works, I tested it by:
`test.frames->size()` and it was 7 as I planned.

So how can I access the vector elements (w and h) at N'th index from the vector?

Comment: also, you don't need to use C-style cast here. Just write `test.frames = &some_animation;`

Comment: @qehgt, ah, i was thinking i did something wrong/overkill there.

Comment: Why would you have an `init_anim` when there are constructors? Writing plain C++ code without to many bells and whistles is often good, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: @pmr, i just made the code as simple as possible. -> dont worry, i do use constructors!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to dererference the pointer before accessing the array. Just like you are doing with the `->` operator to get the size.

```
(*test.frames)[0].w;
```

You could use the `->` operator to also access the `[]` operator method, but the syntax isn't as nice:

```
test.frames->operator[](0).w;
```

If you want to be able to use `[]` directly like a true vector syntactically, then you can either allow the `frames` member to take a copy of the `vector`, you it can reference the `vector`. Or, you can overload `[]` on the `animstruct` itself to use the `[]` syntax on your `test` variable.

Copy:

```
struct animstruct { vector<framestruct> frames; };
animstruct test;
void init_anim(){ test.frames = some_animation; }

test.frames[0].w;
```

Reference:

```
struct animstruct { vector<framestruct> &frames;
                    animstruct (vector<framestruct> &f) : frames(f) {} };
animstruct test(some_animation);
void init_anim(){}

test.frames[0].w;
```

Overload:

```
struct animstruct { vector<framestruct> *frames;
                    framestruct & operator[] (int i) { return (*frames)[i]; } };
animstruct test;
void init_anim(){ test.frames = &some_animation; }

test[0].w;
```

Comment: Hmm, nice trick with the [] operator. Is it anyhow possible to make this accessing look exactly like without a pointer? like `test.frames[0].w` ?

Comment: @Rookie: Since `test.frames` is a pointer, you have to dereference it to get to the `vector` object it is pointing to. If you want to avoid the syntax of the extra dereference, you can change your object to use a reference instead. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Looks pretty complicated, i'll take a look at it later, for now i just use a macro: `#define getframe (*test.frames)` :P

Answer (score 1):

`test.frames` points to a vector, so you need to dereference it before indexing into the vector.

```
(*test.frames)[0].w
```